# Perl one-liner to expand Unix environment variables

Tags: perl, unix

I've a Perl script which does the job of expanding the Unix environment variables. The script is working fine. The script is as below:

```
# I know this should not be typed here. This is here just for testing.
@ENV{qw(LKUP_DIR DATA_DIR CTRL_DIR MMM)} = qw(/appl1/TSS/lkup /appl1/TSS/data /appl1/TSS/ctrl Oct);
while ( <DATA> )
{
  my $line=$_;
  chomp $line;
  $line =~ s{\$(\w+)}{ exists $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : '$'.$1 }ge;
  $line =~ s{\$\{(\w+)\}}{ exists $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : '${'.$1.'}' }ge;
  print "$line\n";
}

__DATA__
${LKUP_DIR}/lookup_file.txt
${CTRL_DIR}/ctrl_file_$MMMM.txt
$CTRL_DIR/ctrl_file_$MMM.txt
```

I want to convert this script into an one-liner, but I am not sure how handle the single quotes around the $ in the regular expression used in the script mentioned above. I tried the below, but of course it is not working:

```
perl -lne '$line=$_; $line =~ s{\$(\w+)}{ exists $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : '$'.$1 }ge; $line =~ s{\$\{(\w+)\}}{ exists $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : '${'.$1.'}' }ge; print "$line";' DATA.txt
```

Any suggestions? (I want to do this only in Perl.)

Comment: Why do you _have to_ change that to a one-liner?

Comment: @MAT: For the purpose of brevity and also one less script to maintain. I am planning to use the one-liner in shell scripts to create arrays.

Comment: That's a really bad tradeoff. The oneliner is much less readable than the script. Whatever you save that oneliner in must also be maintained, and that will be harder to do than a readable, commented script. Version control tools (diff for ex.) on one-liners is near useless. Really, you should reconsider. `perl processData.pl DATA.TXT` is much, much better.

Comment: @SachinS: Rather than copying a one-liner all over the place, put the readable version of the script in a file and use the name of the script all over the place. It's even shorter than the one-liner, and you don't have to obfuscate code to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Mat: it seems a bad idea. It will be just one line but you lose on readability. Just think that you might edit a year later and still try to understand what the one liner does.

But  anyway, in Perl you can use `q/STRING/` instead of `'STRING'`.

```
perl -lne '$line=$_; $line =~ s{\$(\w+)}{ exists $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : q/$/.$1 }ge; $line =~ s{\$\{(\w+)\}}{ exists $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : q/${/.$1.q/}/ }ge; print "$line";' DATA.txt
```

Comment: +1 for the `q//` solution to the single-quotes inside of single-quotes issue, and for your qualification.  `q//` is much more readable than the alternative: `perl -lne '$line=$_; $line =~ s{\$(\w+)}{ exists $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : '\''$'\''.$1 }ge; $line =~ s{\$\{(\w+)\}}{ exists $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : '\''${'\''.$1.'\''}'\'' }ge; print "$line";' DATA.txt`  :)  But of course "don't do this" is the best advice.

Comment: @Matteo : I am not sure if I should open a new question for this but following is not working:
set -A arr `perl -lne '$line=$_; $line =~ s{\$(\w+)}{ exists $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : q/$/.$1 }ge; $line =~ s{\$\{(\w+)\}}{ exists $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : q/${/.$1.q/}/ }ge; print "$line";' DATA.txt`

I get following errors:
syntax error at -e line 1, near "+)"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

(I have wrapped the perl command in back-quote - but some how it is not getting displayed above)

Comment: Don't use ``` but `set -A $( perl ... )` and it should work. For the rest I don't know since neither my Mac (BSD) nor Linux `set` have a `-A` option.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more concise version of your script. A notable difference is that I use `//` instead of `exists`. I think that the difference, where environment variables are concerned, would be negligible. If an environment variable exists, but is undefined, what is it? If it truly would be undefined, it would cause a warning when perl prints it.

```
perl -wpe 's#\${?(\w+)}?# $ENV{$1} // $& #ge;' DATA.txt
```

If you still insist on using `exist`, simply use:

```
perl -wpe 's#\${?(\w+)}?# exists $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : $& #ge;' DATA.txt
```

What I did:

- Removed the useless transition variable `$line`
- Removed `-l` option
- Exchanged `-n` and `print` with `-p`
- Change delimiter on the substitution to not have to escape `{}`
- Combined the regexes by adding `}?` as an optional match
- Used `$&` -- entire match -- instead of trying to puzzle the parts of
  the match back together